# Hard-wiring my Temporary power pole to my job site

Tags: electrical, security

Wife and I purchased an unfinished house just before covid. The majority of work remaining is unlicensed and cosmetic (doors, trim, paint, floors etc.), which I can do myself. In the last 2 months we've had numerous break in attempts at the job site. I've added window bars and security doors, but was hoping to light the property up to further discourage trespassing and future break in attempts. The job site currently only has a temporary/construction pole for power. I understand the logistics/mechanics of wiring, so my question is:
Can a licensed electrician legally hard-wire power from the temp pole to the house to feed flood and porch lights?

Comment: Might be jurisdiction-dependent: Where are you?

Comment: We're located in New Olreans.

Answer (score 2):

If the electric panel, meter can and house wiring is complete, just have the electrical inspected and have the power company run the service. A electrician can run from a breaker on the temp power pole to the house electric, even if it's not all complete, but it would have to be inspected. Keep in mind that anyone could just shut off the breaker and there go your lights.
Note: This is/was allowed in Florida but you'd have to check with your local people.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. The main breaker box for the house still needs to be wired and because of several repairs and alterations at least two more lines need to be added. I can always put a lock on the temp pole box cover to help protect at that end. We have financing right now specifically for the floors etc., which is why i was exploring quick and easy options for security lighting.

Comment: Even though the panel's  wiring isn't complete, is the weatherhead installed with wiring? could they make the panel hot?

Comment: No, the weatherhead is not currently connected to the grid, the heavy feeder lines run from the breaker box to the exterior mounted meter box, but not up to the weatherhead.

Comment: @DMW  but is it connected to the panel?

Comment: the heavy feeder lines run from the breaker box to the exterior mounted meter box, but not up to the weatherhead. And thank you for your patience. I thought it might be easier to hash things out here in writing before I call a local professional.